# Delete the parent directory (non-empty) if a specific child directory is empty

Tags: command-line, directory, find

I have to keep all the directory which contains files in a specific subdirectory but to delete rest all directories in which subdirectory is empty.

To be more specific here is the structure:

```
A
|
|--------312311
|       |
|       |----Recording
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
|
|
|--------453453
|       |----Recording
|                   |
|                   |-------a.mp3
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
|
|
|--------566532
|       |----Recording
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
```

The subdirectories may or may not contain a file. So I need to delete the whole directory like '312311' & '566532' and only '453453' should be left with all data in it because it has a file in 'Recording' folder which is a specific directory for me.

I saw many posts but it links to many specific file names. Any help will be much appreciated as I need to do many times in a week.

Comment: Is Recording always on the first level in the directory? Also: are all folders on the first level inside the main directory?

Comment: A is the top level directory in which it contains numbered directories . And in the numbered directories it contains 'Recording'  folder as well as some 'txt' files as in eg. And in 'Recording' it may or may not contain files..

Comment: Will you remove the picture of your text and place the actual text into your question.  Pictures of text are cumbersome to for us to process.  Using the actual text is substantially more convenient, among other inherent conveniences.

Comment: i did the same asked by you James..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The script below will do exactly as you describe, it:

1. lists the folders inside a directory
2. Looks inside each of the folders for a folder named "Recording"

   - If it exists *and* is empty, it deletes its superior folder
   - if it does *not* exist, it also deletes its superior folder
   - ***files*** on the first level inside A will not be deleted.

In an image:

```
A
|
|--------123456
|       |
|       |----Recording
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
|
|
|--------635623
|       |----Recording
|                   |
|                   |-------a.mp3
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
|
|
|--------123456
|       |----Recording
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
|
|--------Monkey.txt
```

will result in:

```
A
|
|
|--------635623
|       |----Recording
|                   |
|                   |-------a.mp3
|       |----a.txt
|       |----b.txt
|
|
|--------Monkey.txt
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import shutil

dr = sys.argv[1]

def path(*args):
    return os.path.join(*args)

for d in os.listdir(dr):
    try:
        if not os.listdir(path(dr, d, "Recording")):
            shutil.rmtree(path(dr,d))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        shutil.rmtree(path(dr,d))
    except NotADirectoryError:
        pass
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `delete_empty.py`
2. Run it with the (full!) directory (containinf your subdirs, A in your example) as argument by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/delete_empty.py /path/to/directory
   ```

That's it.

#### Explanation

Feeding the content of your folder "A" to the script,

```py
os.listdir(dr)
```

will list its subdirectories (and files). Then:

```py
if not os.listdir(path(dr, d, "Recording"))
```

will try to list the content of each of the (sub)folders, which will raise an error if the item is a file:

```py
except NotADirectoryError
    pass
```

or if the folder "Recording" does not exist at all:

```py
FileNotFoundError
    shutil.rmtree(path(dr,d))
```

If the folder "Recording" exists *and* is empty, the superior folder is removed:

```py
if not os.listdir(path(dr, d, "Recording")):
    shutil.rmtree(path(dr,d))
```

---

### EDIT

Additionally, as requested in comments, a version that will check for multiple subdirs (names).

In case the directory contains *any* of the listed (un- empty) subdirs, the directory is kept. Else it will be deleted.

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `delete_empty.py`
2. Run it with the (full!) directory (containing your subdirs, A in your example) and the names of subdirs as arguments by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/delete_empty.py /path/to/directory <subdir1> <subdir2> <subdir3>
   ```

That's it.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]; matches = sys.argv[2:]

def path(*args):
    return os.path.join(*args)

for d in os.listdir(dr):
    # delete directory *unless* either one of the listed subdirs has files
    keep = False
    # check for each of the listed subdirs(names)
    for name in matches:
        try:
            if os.listdir(path(dr, d, name)):
                keep = True
                break
        except NotADirectoryError:
            # if the item is not a dir, no use for other names to check
            keep = True
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # if the name (subdir) does not exist, check for the next
            pass
    if not keep:
        # if there is no reason to keep --> delete
        shutil.rmtree(path(dr,d))
```

#### Note

Please first run on a test directory to make sure it does exactly what you want.

Comment: this code really helped and it worked as said. Thanks for the code . Really helpful.

Comment: Suppose if I need to keep and check two folders or more , how will I be able to do in this code ? adding 'OR' or  pipe ' | '  somewhere..  suggest sumthing !

Comment: Hi @DerekJames that only requires a minor edit, I will post this afternoon.

Comment: @Derek, wait, should the superior folder be removed if *any* of the folders is empty, or all? Could there be multiple of them in one superior dir?

Comment: Suppose @Jacob , I have two folders 'Recording' And 'Video' . It should check both. If any of the subfolders contain the file the folder '635623' shud not be deleted. 
And also the ability to add more folders to check if it can be done..

Comment: If any of the folder contains data , it should not delete the superior folder..

Comment: Wait do I understand correctly that in either one of the (sub) folders a *specific* file is existing, it should not be deleted, or *any* file?

Comment: In either one of the specific (sub) folders which we give in code,  any file is existing, folder should not be deleted .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56093/discussion-between-derek-james-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: Hi @DerekJames, posted!

Answer (score 11):

Using `find` and `xargs`:

```
find A -type d -name 'Recording' -empty -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 echo rm -rf
```

(remove the `echo` once you are comfortable that it is identifying the correct directories). The `printf '%h\0` part prints the (null terminated) parent directory - from `man find`:

```
       %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last ele‐
              ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
              in  the  current  directory)  the %h specifier expands to
              ".".
```

Ex.: given

```
$ tree A
A
├── 312311
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.txt
│   └── Recording
├── 453453
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.txt
│   └── Recording
│       └── a.mp3
└── 566532
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── Recording

6 directories, 7 files
```

then

```
$ find A -type d -name 'Recording' -empty -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 rm -rf
$ 
$ tree A
A
└── 453453
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── Recording
        └── a.mp3

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: find A -type d -name 'Recording' -empty -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 echo rm -rf 

this is just printing " rm -rf"

AND
find A -type d -name 'Recording' -empty -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 rm -rf  
is not working... 

Am I doing something wrong..

Comment: @DerekJames you need to replace A with the actual directory.

Comment: Would it be ok to put in a regular expression in place of the _Recording_ name since the OP gave files names with numbers, say `[\d]*`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm : I replaced with actual directory but still not wrking ?

Comment: @DerekJames that is odd! it worked on my system, but you might have forgotten to cd into the directory first? Waitwait, that should not matter...

Comment: I suggest to replace `rm -rf` with `rmdir --` as this is immune to race conditions where files get added with after `find` but before `rm` and is not prone to bogus characters in directory names.

Comment: And why not just `find . -empty -type d -delete`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaxRied unless I have misinterpreted the question, the OP wants to delete the (non empty) parent if a specific child directory is empty - I don't think `rmdir` or `-delete` helps in this case. Otherwise I would have agreed with you.

Comment: @steeldriver said correctly .. I need to "delete the (non empty) parent if a specific child directory is empty" .. and yes this line will be an amp title for this thread.. right ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler bash solution:

```
for d in */; do rmdir "$d/Recording" && rm -r "$d"; done
```

It works because `rmdir` will fail if the directory is not empty, and `&&` will prevent the `rm -r` from being executed unless `rmdir` succeeds. The glob `*/` makes sure you're only working on the directories, so other files will not be affected.

Comment: Smart thinking! +1